# Pageview for Facebook Instant Articles in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-analytics, instant

I have implemented the google analytical code at my instant article, but its 
showing a big difference between google analytic and facebook instant pageview, I have implemented following code

```js
 ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('set', 'campaignSource', 'Facebook-Instant'); 
ga('set',  'campaignMedium', 'Instant Article');
ga('send', 'pageview', window.location.href); 
ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname);
```

can you please let me know why both analytic had pageview difference

Comment: I also have this problem. however I dont set any other parameters in ```'send'``` than ```ga('send', 'pageview')```

Comment: It would be great if you could share the full snippet.